# Lua code Building Fortnite issues with repeat function

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

Hi as i was asked to I ask a question by issue I have on my whole code.

This code is what I did to be able to build both wall and floor by pressing MB4 and MB5 on my G502 Lightspeed :

```
----------------
-- Boutton 4 sol ou sol et toit - MB4 floor or floor and roof
----------------

                if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
                  PlayMacro("PlusReso")

                  if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                       FastSleep(1)
                    PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                       FastSleep(1)

                  end

                  if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                    PressAndReleaseKey(7)
                    FastSleep(1)
                    -- Petite Boucle - Little Loop
                    for i=1, 20 do
                    for j=1, 5 do
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F4")-- Toit - Roof
                       FastSleep(1)
                    PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                       FastSleep(1)
                    end
                    for j=1, 5 do
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                       FastSleep(1)
                    PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                       FastSleep(1)
                    end
                    end

                  end

                  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 4) then
                    if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
                    ReleaseKey("F6")
                    PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                    PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
                    end

                end

----------------
-- Boutton 5 mur ou sol et mur - MB5 wall or wall and floor
----------------

                if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
                    PlayMacro("PlusReso")

                    if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                    repeat
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                    FastSleep(1)

                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mode construction Mur
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                    FastSleep(1)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
                    ReleaseKey("F6")
                    PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                    end

                    if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                    repeat
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mode construction Mur
                    FastSleep(1)
                    PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                    FastSleep(1)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
                    if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                    ReleaseKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                    PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                    PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
                    end
                    end
                end
```

My first code was more simple with a repeat loop on MB4 and MB5 but when both were pressed they couldn't work together.

Something like this :

If MB4 pressed
repeat floor build
until not MB4 pressed

If MB pressed
repeat floor build
until not MB5 pressed

Before that I was just using macros on MB4 and MB5 to build. It was fine but some walls or floors weren't build when I moved my mouse very fast. Lua permits me to have a very fast building experience.

So how can i have both loops repeating together please? What am I missing?

The second issue is the macro increase and decrease dpi (PlusReso and MoinsReso). It works good but sometimes I still stuck in high dpi after releasing all my mouse buttoms making it impossible to aim.

Can we make a simple code to increase and decrease dpi without using macros and being sure not to still stuck in high dpi after releasing one or several buttoms?

Thanks

Comment: How `PlusReso` and `MoinsReso` are defined?

Comment: They are macros on the logitech Ghub not binded to any buttom. The macros works are simple. PlusReso just increase DPI and MoinsReso decrease it. My default DPI is set at 800 and I only have an other one defined at 3000 on my mouse.

Comment: Try to insert `Sleep(30)` before and after `PlayMacro("MoinsReso")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptnuff Thanks for the code below. It didn't work at first but suddenly it did. Don't ask me why. The good thing is that both walls and floors are build together very fast no matter wich button pressed first. The same for RMB with roofs.

Comment: Help me to understand please =  why using local at beguining and not at end of the script?  I tried to add the stairs to your code but local MB6 = IsMouseButtonPressed(6) gives an error (I knew it but I tried) and local MB6 = (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) doesn't work. My stairs  as you guessed is MB6 and can't be changed. Thanks

Comment: `IsMouseButtonPressed(6)` is invalid: this function accepts only 1-5.  This is because Windows assumes there can not be more than 5 buttons on a mouse.

Comment: @Egor Ah ok it's Win10 who is guilty I thought lua was the cause of this limit. Will win11 change this ? Is there any way to do the same with (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) with a function or maybe by binding "lalt" or something like this to MB6?

Comment: 1) `it's Win10 who is guilty` - No.  It's Logitech.  Logitech mouses have more buttons than allowed :-)  Windows will probably never change this limit.  2) Yes, you can bind lalt to MB6 and achieve what you want.  But your game must ignore lalt.

Comment: Oh ok i'll try that. IsModifierPressed("lalt") and bind lalt to my MB6 in ghub without using lalt anywhere else in game. I'll post the code after that if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can i have both loops repeating together please?

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 4 or arg == 5) then
   Sleep(10)
   local MB4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
   local MB5 = IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   if MB4 or MB5 then
      PlayMacro("PlusReso")
      repeat
         local RMB = IsMouseButtonPressed(3)

         if MB4 then
            PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
            FastSleep(1)
            PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
            FastSleep(1)
         end

         if MB5 then
            PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mode construction Mur
            FastSleep(1)
            PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
            FastSleep(1)
         end

         if RMB then
            PressAndReleaseKey("F4")-- Toit - Roof
            FastSleep(1)
            PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
            FastSleep(1)
         end

         MB4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
         MB5 = IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
      until not (MB4 or MB5)
      ReleaseKey("F6")
      PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
      PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code. I used "rctrl" and it works almost perfectly, fast and with no issues in building.
I added several action to MB4 and MB6 when RMB is pressed giving me two actions with each mouse button by pressing RMB or not.
I had to add the same action to MB5 with RMB or i was having an issue like stopping the loop or a DPI issue ! I can put an other action if needed here.

The only problem is that sometimes I still stuck in high DPI (very more often in game then creatif) when editing using the reste of my code but this is an other question.

Thanks Egor you rocks ;)

```
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 4 or arg == 5 or arg == 6) then
   
        FastSleep(10)
        local MB4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
        local MB5 = IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
        local MB6 = IsModifierPressed("rctrl")
   
       if MB4 or MB5 or MB6 then
          PlayMacro("PlusReso")
        repeat
            local RMB = IsMouseButtonPressed(3)

            if MB4 then
                PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
            end

            if MB5 then
                if not RMB then
                PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mur - Wall
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
                end
            end
         
            if MB6 then
                PressAndReleaseKey("F3")-- Escalier - Stair
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
            end

            if RMB and MB4 then
                PressAndReleaseKey("F4")-- Toit - Roof
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
            end
            
            if RMB and MB5 then
                PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mur - Wall
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
            end
            
            if RMB and MB6 then
                PressAndReleaseKey("F3")-- Escalier - Stair
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
                
                PressAndReleaseKey("F4")-- Toit - Roof
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
                
                PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                FastSleep(1)
                PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                FastSleep(1)
                
            end
            
                MB4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
                MB5 = IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
                MB6 = IsModifierPressed("rctrl")
                
          until not (MB4 or MB5 or MB6)
            ReleaseKey("F6")
            PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
            PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
       end
    end
```

Comment: Hi. I'm still trying to improve DPI issues with this code. Nothing is working. One thing i hoped could work is by deleting => PlayMacro("PlusReso") and PlayMacro("MoinsReso") from my script and just create a macro that up (when pressed) and down (when released) my DPI and bind it to each button i need it to. The problem is that when a macro is bind on G4,5 or 6 the lua script doesn't works anymore. As if it doesn't see that any of these buttoms are pressed !!! Any help please to make work the macro and the lua together.